# listview.pointToPosition providing INVALID value when should not

Tags: android, android-listview, drag-and-drop

I am getting information from my application in production, but when I am trying to reproduce the problem I am not able to do it. What I am looking for is any idea (as I am blocked) of how can I try to reproduce the error.

Basically I am having an activities with a listview, toolbar, edittext and admob  advertisement.

My listview is composed of a relativealayout containing a textview and one imageview.

With the adapter I am attaching to the textview an OnLongClickListener that starts a drag operation.

To the Listview itself, I am adding an OnDragListener.

```
 @TargetApi(11)
 public class myDragEventListener implements View.OnDragListener {
        // This is the method that the system calls when it dispatches a drag event to the
        // listener.
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            // Defines a variable to store the action type for the incoming event
            final int action = event.getAction();
            // Handles each of the expected events
            switch(action) {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                    return true;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    //We detect which is the item where the drop happened on.
                    int itemPosition = listShop.pointToPosition((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());

                // An unknown action type was received.
                default:
                    return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

So, basically we initiate the drag on the textview from the listview item and the drop ends on the listview itself.

This code works properly, but I received from production reports that sometimes the value of itemPosition to be -1. To avoid an exception I can add a simple check, but I am worried about the user experience.

So, what I would like to avoid is a bad user experience with the application not responding properly, and we know is happening due to reports. The problem is that we are not able to reproduce.

Trying to reproduce this error we tried:

- Longclick on textview and drop on imageview. (provides correct itemPosition)
- Longclick on textivew and drop outside the listview (drag listener not called)
- Longclick on textivew and drop at the edge of listview (works ok).

Does somebody has a suggestion of how this "-1" could be reproduced? Theoretically it should not happen.... is the drop (whatever the drag that has been initiated) activates the OnDragListener, that means that the position where the drop occurs is a position of the listview. How can the DragListener be called in a listview in an incorrect position?

Any idea what could be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem. My listview covers almost all the screen, and sometimes is feed with items in the list that are not covering the complete list up to the end. When an item is dragged and dropped in the space where there is no item in the list, provide that value.

The problem is that my testing mobile is very small compared to other devices, and that mobile was always having the screen fully covered by items of the list, so any drag/drop operation was always captured.